# Why is the Create Reactapp script code set BUILD_PATH= not working in dockerfile?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker

So, I have been having issues deploying my reactjs and nodejs app in the docker container for three days now. It is my first time using docker and I was following a tutorial. The tutor used MAC and I am using windows OS. This is the docker file code:

```
FROM node:lts-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./

COPY client/package*.json client/
RUN npm run install-client  --only=production


COPY server/package*.json server/
RUN npm run install-server  --only=production


COPY client/ client/
RUN npm run build --prefix client


COPY server/ server/


USER node

CMD [ "npm", "start", "--prefix", "server" ]

EXPOSE 5000
```

The major problem comes from the `RUN npm run build --prefix client.
This code calls the npm script from the client side (Reactjs) via the package.json file which is written like this:

```
"build": "set BUILD_PATH=../server/public && react-scripts build",
```

This script set a buid_path in my server folder called public and created the react build files inside it.

Somehow, these two actions don't work in my dockerfile. When I call the `run build --prefix client` in my dockerfile, it doesn't create the react build file and doesn't set a folder.
When I tried to remove the `set BUILD_PATH=../server/public &&`  in my react package.json file and run only the create react build script `react-scripts build`, dockerfile did perform the action by creating the react build file as expected in a folder called 'build'. But the build files surely were done inside the client-side.

I am looking for a way to create the react build files inside my server folder. That is inside the node. Is there a way I can achieve this successfully with docker? Is there a script I can use that works with docker? The reason I want to place my react build files inside my node server is to enable me run both on a single port which is my node server port. This is what my app.js looks like:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'public')))


app.get('/*', (req, res)=>{
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'public', 'index.html'));
})
```

`
I am serving the react files from my node port.

Comment: That's not standard Linux (Bourne shell) syntax for running a command with a modified environment variable.  Does `BUILD_PATH=../server/public react-scripts build` work any better?  You could also build the front-end in its default place and `RUN mv` the files into their destination, or use a multi-stage build for this.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help out. Please could you tell me more about using Run mv and how to implement it? Or point me to an article you think can explain the both options you mentioned to me. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

I sorted out my problem after. So, here is the problem. This script line in my reactjs package.json file works well in windows:

```
"build": "set BUILD_PATH=../server/public && react-scripts build",
```

But it didn't work in docker. So, I changed it to this code:

```
"client-build": "BUILD_PATH=../server/public react-scripts build",
```

Now, when I called the `RUN npm run client-build --prefix client` in dockerfile, it did what I wanted it to do which was to create a folder in my server and run the react build files in it.
The app is working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Please, also note that if you use this line on Windows, make sure there is no space between 'public' and '&&' (so '.../public&& react...), otherwise there will be a gap in the path for some of the files you need to push to your repository.

Here's the correct version:

"build": "set BUILD_PATH=../server/public&& react-scripts build",

Answer (score 0):

Just complementing your solution: It did so happen because the first approach to set a BUILD_PATH works only on Windows, and the second one works on Linux, which is the environment your image was built.

Windows:

```html
"build": "set BUILD_PATH=../server/public && react-scripts build",
```

Linux:

```html
"client-build": "BUILD_PATH=../server/public react-scripts build",
```